# I want to send a list of users who reacted to my message but the list always shows empty

Tags: discord, discord.py

I searched it up and saw someone do it like this but it always returns an empty list

```
@bot.command()
async def spinthewheel(ctx,msg:discord.Message=None):
  guild=ctx.guild
  if msg==None:
    em=discord.Embed(title="SPIN THE WHEEL!!", description="React to this message with ⚡ to enter!",color=discord.Color.from_str('#ff00ff'))
    msg=await ctx.send(embed=em)
    await msg.add_reaction('⚡')

  else:
    await msg.add_reaction('⚡')
    await ctx.send("Reaction has been added",delete_after=10)

  await asyncio.sleep(5)

  users = list()
  for reaction in msg.reactions:
    if reaction.emoji == '⚡':
      async for user in reaction.users():
        if user != bot.user:
          users.append(user.name)
  user_list="\n".join(user.name for user in users)
  await ctx.send(f"users: {user_list}")
```

I tried using this one too but same results

```
users = [user async for user in reaction.users()]
```

Can you pls tell me how to fix this? Thanks <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `msg.reactions` is empty - this is because it's the message representation at the time it was created and hasn't been updated since with the reaction information. This is easily fixable with a:

```py
msg = await msg.fetch()
```

This will fetch the message anew from the channel. Just put it after your `asyncio.sleep` and before you loop over the reactions.

Comment: [`msg = awat msg.fetch()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.fetch) is a cleaner way of doing the same thing.